# How to Change Google Maps Street View's Lat/Long based on Hour

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API for Street View and then change each location based on the hour. My code is in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zhGxF/3/

At first I put the google view into an iframe and then used jquery's attr. method to change out the URL. I ran into too many problems with X-Frame blocking that I couldn't find a solution for.  Therefore, I jumped into the API.

At first, the code in the jsfiddle was at least displaying Fenway park, but now I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"

Does anyone have a working example of not only to the google street view maps API with panorama but also a way to change each lat/long based on the clock?

Javascript from docs:

```
 function initialize() {
  var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);

  var panoOptions = {
    position: fenway,
    addressControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    },
    linksControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    enableCloseButton: false
  };

  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: [updated fiddle that shows StreetView](http://jsfiddle.net/zhGxF/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any idea how to change the location based on the clock javascript?

Comment: I don't see any code in your fiddle to even attempt that.  You need to define how you want the location to change based on the time.